# Don't understand how author gets 'from $A$ to $B$' (Radial functions/matrices)

Tags: analysis

I basically have a technical problem that I've encountered whilst reading my notes, all under the presumption that the below function $u$ is radial:

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u,v:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $v(x) = u(Rx)$ where $R = (R_{ij})_{i,j = 1,...,n} \in SO(n)$

(Or in other words, $R$ is an $n\times n$ matrix s.t. $RR^T = R^TR = I_n$)

It is at this point when the author takes, intially, the first derivative of $v$ with respect to $x_i$ and then the second derivative with respect to $x_k$ that I get very, very confused; for he writes that, $$v_{x_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}u_{x_j}(Rx)R_{ji}$$

And then subsequently that, $$v_{x_i x_k} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}v_{x_j x_l}(Rx)R_{ji}R_{lk} = (R^THR)_{ik}$$ Where $H := \text{Hess}(u(Rx))$. I've tried hopelessly to work out why these are true by writing out the full versions of $Rx$ and then trying to do everything one by one but I can't quite work out how to get these results even so!

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=Rx.$ Then $y_j = \sum_{k=1}^n R_{jk} x_k.$  Observe that 
$$
\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_k} = R_{jk}.
$$
Then 
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_k}(x)=\underset{\text{Chain Rule}}{\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} [u(y)] =  \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial y_j} (y)  \frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_k}}}  = \sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} (y)  R_{jk}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to do the second one and almost got there; its a bit of a messy calculation really and fortunately not wholely relevant in itself to my course.